# Use external FTP server for file upload in Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, ftp, upload

I have a form in Zend 1.11 which uploads files to the server with

```
$imageUploader = $this->createElement('file', 'docs');
$imageUploader->setDestination($uploadPath);
```

The upload path now is on the same server but I want to upload to a external FTP server.

When I set uploadPath to ftp://user:pass@externalserver.com:21/folder I get "The given destination is not writable" but this folder has 0777

How can I set up a connection to this FTP server and upload the files there?

Comment: Are you sure your user is allowed to write in that directory.. FTP servers work with a “Home” directory where it is only allowed to write/read files from..

Comment: Yes, in this folder (0777) I can add and delete files for example in filezilla. Only the parent folder is not writable.

Comment: ok in that case can you share more code? That current code is a bit to minimal to see what you are doing or trying to do here.

Comment: Is there a specific part you would need to see? I will post this